# Catch error - setShowActionsInCompactView

Tags: react-native

I try to use https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control package for my project but every time I catch error: 
**`setShowActionsInCompactView: action 0 out of bounds (max -1)`**

My code is from demo app:

```
MusicControl.enableBackgroundMode(true);
MusicControl.setNowPlaying({
      title: 'Billie Jean',
      artwork: 'https://i.imgur.com/e1cpwdo.png',
      artist: 'Michael Jackson',
      album: 'Thriller',
      genre: 'Post-disco, Rhythm and Blues, Funk, Dance-pop',
      duration: this.whoosh.getDuration(),
      description: 'Billie Jean is a song by American singer Michael Jackson. It is the second single from the singer\'s sixth solo album, Thriller (1982). It was written and composed by Jackson and produced by Jackson and Quincy Jones.',
      date: '1983-01-02T00:00:00Z',
      rating: 84
    })
    MusicControl.enableControl('play', false)
    MusicControl.enableControl('pause', true)
```

I have reduced the code to simple invoke:

```
MusicControl.setNowPlaying({
      title: 'Billie Jean',
})
```

But the error is still throwing. 
Then I have tried run demo project https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control-demo as it is and again I failed with the same error

I have found a lot of projects using this package and code is familiar with mine. 
Could any give me a hint where I make mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

broken current package verison - 0.9.8

disscussion https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control/issues/230