# Fatal exception : Couldn't inflate contentViewsjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setShowActionsInCompactView: action 0 out of bounds (max -1)

Tags: flutter, firebase-test-lab, just-audio, audio-service

i use test lab to find bugs on my apps and i have an but that i can't find the origins. I think it came from just_audio or audio_service.

This is the test issues :

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification(tag=null, id=1124) posted from package com.our_unseen_nature, crashing app(uid=10274, pid=22490): Couldn't inflate contentViewsjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setShowActionsInCompactView: action 0 out of bounds (max -1)
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.our_unseen_nature, PID: 22490
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification(tag=null, id=1124) posted from package com.our_unseen_nature, crashing app(uid=10274, pid=22490): Couldn't inflate contentViewsjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setShowActionsInCompactView: action 0 out of bounds (max -1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2005)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: That's coming from audio_service. Consider filing a bug report to get it fixed.

Comment: Do any of these links help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588020/catch-error-setshowactionsincompactview

https://github.com/google/flutter.plugins/issues/95

https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all, I've found the solution and It was really easy. The error occured because i didn't choose correctly the actions to show in Android's compact view based by those i've selected as my controls.

```
 controls: [
     MediaControl. skipToPrevious,
     MediaControl.pause,
     MediaControl.skipToNext,
   ],
 
   // Which controls to show in Android's compact view
   //from the lists of controls selected.
   androidCompactActionIndices: const[0, 1, 2],
```